# div not being scrollable

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the wrapper div scrollable when elements inside exceed the width of the wrapper. I applied `overflow: auto` but it is not making it scrollable. What am I missing and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  column-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: gold;
}

.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The width of the container is not enough to see the scroll, try to increase the with and see.

Comment: @Ankit that's not the problem 100px per container should have made the wrapper scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `flex` makes its children shrink and grow

By default, a flex item (i.e. a child element inside a flex container) will grow or shrink flexibly. Thus, the naming "flexbox."

In your snippet, even though you specified `width: 100px;` to `.container` elements, you haven't specified its `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink` values.

Try giving `.container` a specific `flex` value that stops them from growing/shrinking.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: left;
  column-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: gold;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's right. Thanks! Also, just assigning ```flex-shrink: 0; ``` achieved what I sought.

Answer (score 0):

You need set `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to 0 for set shrink factor of container. Try replace `width: 100px` with `flex: 0 0 100px`.

```css
.container {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```